# AngularJS set default selected option in dropdown

Tags: angularjs, ng-options

I am relatively new to AngularJS. Learning every bit of it. I have been worked on KnockoutJS for couple of years and find it comfortable to work on JavaScript.

I am working on a simple Task Manager app which has following JSON as a result on API call for individual task.

```
{
                      "Id": 1,
                      "title": "Culpa nisi irure qui consectetur non reprehenderit incididunt mollit voluptate culpa enim.",
                      "description" : "test description",
                      "owner": "Hunter Mcdonald",
                      "priority": 1,
                      "isActive": false,
                      "picture": "http://placehold.it/100x100",
                      "registered": "2014-12-29T17:13:33"
                  }
```

The meaning of priority values is :

**1** - High, **0** - Neutral, **-1** - Low

The value that I receive from server is strictly in numerical..

However while building the edit form, I want to show these priorities in user understandable text i.e. "High", "Low", "Normal"

[image]

I have created array of objects to achieve this -

```
vm.priorityOptions = [
    { name: "low", value: -1 },
    { name: "normal", value: 0 },
    { name: "high", value: 1 }
];
```

Now, I want to select default selected priority from the API response I get that is `"priority" : 1`. Since it is numerical value, I don't know how can I select default selected option in `vm.priorityOptions`

Any help or helpful snippet on the same?

Comment: With ng-model in select for example like .

<select ng-model="responseObject.priority"></select> .. try this, it should work.

Comment: you can also use track by in case you want to bind full object, but server is giving you only the value part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ngOptions` directive on `<select>`:

```
<select ng-options="item.value as item.name for item in vm.priorityOptions" 
        ng-model="vm.data.priority">
</select>
```

Here is a working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/z9noDWvOTaEdjZZsdY5Z?p=preview).

Answer (score 2):

you can easily achieve this using ng-model

```
<select ng-model="serverResponse.priority">
       <option ng-repeat="item in priorities" value="{{item.value}}">{{item.name}}</option>
</select>
```

serverResponse.priority will be automatically selected

Comment: Thanks for the effort and help :-)